# Multiple tabs are being controlled by the same service worker

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, lighthouse, angular-service-worker

So I opened my PWA in Stackblitz editor. After that I copied the URL of the app and opened it in a new window. Then I used lighthouse Chrome extension to test the PWA, but I get an error "Multiple tabs are being controlled by the same service worker" How can I get over this error? I tried testing in the editor itself and that isn't working since it's testing the editor and not my app.

Answer (score 1):

The *"Multiple tabs are being controlled by the same service worker"* message indicates that the app you are trying to test with Lighthouse tool is probably opened in **more than one** of your browser tabs.

Try to close the other tabs with your app and refresh - this should fix it and you should be able to perform the Lighhouse audit.